# correct use of actionListener in java

Tags: java, user-interface

Im new to java and im trying to build a simple GUI with several buttons and drop down menus. Ive managed to get a working GUI but the real question is about the proper use of the actionListener method. In order to assign an action to a button i inserted each actionListener in its own class, this is the code:

```
public class GUI implements something
{
    public static ClientGUI App;
    private JFrame chatWin;
    private JMenuBar menubar;
    private JMenu x;
    private JMenu y;
    private JMenuItem exit;
    private JMenuItem about;


    public GUI()
    {

               /* 
                * some code and parameters
                */

            //creating the menu bar
            JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
            chatWin.setJMenuBar(menubar);

            JMenu x= new JMenu("menu1");
            menubar.add(x);
            JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("menu2");
            x.add(exit);

            JMenu y= new JMenu("Help");
            menubar.add(help);
            JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("inner menu1");
            y.add(about);

            //action listener for the exit button 
            class exitaction implements ActionListener
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            exit.addActionListener(new exitaction());

            //action listener for the about button
            class aboutaction implements ActionListener
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    //some code
                }

            }
        }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                App = new GUI();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Is that code is considered to be neat and correct? is there anything i could improve or need to change?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I follow the rule:

If the action implementation is great, I put in a inner class.

```
    public MyFrame extends JFrame {

       // componentes creating, etc

        private static class MyShortAction implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                // some big implementation
            }

        }

    }
```

When short, i put in a anonymous class.

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        // some small code
    }

});
```

If it is used by other components, I extract to a top level class.

```
public class MyAction implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        // some small code
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you all guys, that really helped! big thanks Marcio, i used your advice and it works beautifully!

Comment: Yes, I also liked your rules. Obrigado :-P

Answer (score 0):

It will work, but you can implement that in a separated class or even in the main class instead of creating a nested class for every button...

```
public class GUI implements something,ActionListener
{
    //...
    public GUI()
    {
        //...
        exit.setActionListener(this);
        about.setActionListener(this);
        //...
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if(source == exit)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        } else if(source == about)
        {
            //action
        }
    }
}
```

You could also set an action command to the items and compare the string instead of the object.

```
public class GUI implements something,ActionListener
{
    //...
    public GUI()
    {
        //...
        exit.setActionCommand("exit");
        exit.addActionListener(this);

        about.setActionCommand("about");
        about.addActionListener(this);
        //...
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String action = e.getActionCommand();
        if("exit".equals(action))
        {
            System.exit(0);
        } else if("about".equals(action))
        {
            //action
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd hardly call implementing the listener in the main class an improvement. This exposes an internal detail to public API, and brings subtle issues, for example, if you serialize the button, you'll also serialize the fields in GUI and the superclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Simple direct way to add an action listener to a button:

```
//Create the button
JButton button_save = new JButton("Save");
add(button_save);

// Create the listener
button_save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    //do your stuff when button clicked
    //ex: disable the button
    button_save.setEnabled(false);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your code is already correct (I mean it's working, isn't it). 
The rest is mostly a matter of taste (and usability of your code). For example you may want to reuse your code later or add functionality and other buttons to your program you hadn't considered yet. Therefore try the following rules of thumb:

- **avoid inner classes** – you never know when you want to instantiate an object of that class somewhere else. So, use one file for each class (and btw classes should begin with a capital letter)
- put **each implementation** of the ActionListener **in its own class**. I know this will blow up your project but all your code will be clearly arranged and you can even reuse the functionality. For example your exit button. Maybe you decide to have a second exit button somewhere else in the program, then you could give those two buttons the same ActionListener and thereby the same functionality.

For the compiler it wont make any difference, but for you when your project starts growing and getting more and more complex.

Comment: thanks for the elaborated answer!